# How Linux boot UP without /boot?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, kernel, filesystem-corruption

I have Centos VM on VMware Workstation. I commented the /boot entry in the /etc/fstab for testing purposes. But I found that the system gets boot UP with unmounted /boot file system. How the system get the boot partition info in booting process, if it was not there? Why does not it take to emergency mode?

Comment: The system gets booted by the bootloader (whatever it is for your Centos). The `/boot` entry in `/etc/fstab` is only there so the booted system can put files in there to update the OS. The bootloader itself doesn't need this entry, at all.

Comment: Thank you, dirkt

Answer (score 0):

The `/boot` partition, while not strictly need for system startup, is an important one and should be mounted. Let me do two simple examples of when it is needed:

1. **Kernel recompile:** you will find that your boot partition hosts some files called `config-*`. These files describe the kernel configuration, and are re-read when issuing `make menuconfig` (and similar) when recompiling your kernel. While it is true that this is not the only method to store kernel configuration, it surely is one of the most used/common.
2. **Upgrades:** when you upgrade your distro, the packet manager will eventually download a new kernel and install it under `/boot`. If `/boot` is not mounted, these boot files will be placed in the wrong filesystem and Grub will not recognize them.

In the end, while you surely can have a running system without `/boot`, this is **not** a good idea. At least, you should always mount it when needed - if you know that.

Comment: Thank you so much, Madhubala